# Testing Notebook severe slowdown with newlines

Tags: bugs, testing-and-verification

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.1.0**

---

I am having a severe slowdown problem with Mathematica 10 new Testing Notebook feature (File -> New -> Testing Notebook).

Please try this simple test:

[image: fast test]

Now introduce some newlines and try again:

[image]

The second test is much slower. Now the real problem is that the slowdown increases very very fast if you add more elements to the test. These are my results:

```
 1 ->   0.4 sec
 2 ->   0.4 sec
 3 ->   0.4 sec
 4 ->   0.4 sec
 5 ->   0.4 sec
 6 ->   0.4 sec
 7 ->   0.8 sec
 8 ->   3.7 sec (shown above)
 9 ->  22   sec
10 -> 190   sec
11 -> I don’t want to try
```

For long commands, the tests are much more readable by introducing some line breaks. This is why this problem matters to me.

Can you reproduce this? I am using Mathematica 10.0.2 and Windows 7.

Comment: Reproduced in V10, Windows. Just a bug.

Comment: I still experience unnatural slowdowns with large testing notebooks. Is that by design?

Answer (score 8):

This seems to be a bug in `.../SystemFiles/Components/MUnit/Kernel/Notebooks.m`, probably somewhere in `testOptionPatterns` or `whiteSpaceOrNone` or somewhere there. 
Of course it is nearly impossible to efficiently parse any longer `NotebookRead` box structure with the Kernel pattern matcher, so I would always run test files from .mt files in Workbench, or, if you really need to use the FrontEnd for, o.k., maybe developing test files, then I would just create a simple button like

```
CreatePalette@Button["ToInputForm",((NotebookFind[SelectedNotebook[], #1, All, CellStyle]; 
    FrontEndExecute[{FrontEndToken[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[], 
       "SelectionConvert", "InputForm"]}]) & ) /@ 
  {"VerificationTest", "ExpectedOutput"}]
```

Then select your test notebook with the newlines, then click on the "ToInputForm" button and all "VerificationTest" and "ExpectedOutput" test cells are converted to InputForm and things seem to work fine.

Comment: Thank you Rolf. I'll explore moving into Workbench (at least the test part).

Answer (score 3):

This issue has been fixed in 10.1+

Comment: Please provide a bit more detail, such as the source of your information.

Comment: With 10.1 under Windows 8.1 (64bit), I can confirm that this problem does not occur.